# Docker compose: pass named contexts to docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-build, buildx

I have a docker file that using [multiple build contexts](https://www.docker.com/blog/dockerfiles-now-support-multiple-build-contexts/) copies a file from a named context: `foo`. ie, something like:

```
COPY --from=foo . /bar
```

I can build it like this:

```
docker buildx build --build-context foo=/my/dir/
```

I'd like to be able to pass this named context from a docker-compose file:

- statically, ie hardcoded in docker-compose file.
- dynamically, ie passed to docker-compose file itself.

Comment: very basically => `services: {my_service: {build: {context: ${CONTEXT_FROM_ENV}}}}`. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#illustrative-sample and https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: note that i want to pass a named context, not the default one. in principle there are multiple named contexts I might want to pass.

Comment: see added code snippet which should help clarify the setup.

Comment: See the first documentation link above. It does not look like this is taken in charge yet by docker-compose specification.

Comment: did you read this: https://docs.docker.com/build/customize/bake/compose-file/#extension-field-with-x-bake

Answer (score 4):

I managed to find a partial answer:

The way to pass named contexts to a docker file using the multi-stage semantics is as below:

```
target "target1" {
  context = "../path/to/docker/file"
  contexts = {
    foo = "../path/to/additional/source/contexts"
  }
}
```

we can even pass the context resulting from another build target `target2` like this: `"target:target2"`

The above [bake file](https://docs.docker.com/build/customize/bake/file-definition/) can be baked using `docker buildx bake`

I'm still not clear however how the above can be used in a docker compose file to actually run an image, as opposed to just build it.